# Expander throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: xaml, maui, nullreferenceexception, maui-community-toolkit

I am developing an app using `.Net Maui` and `.Net 7`. In one of my pages, I need to show a list of our clients with their names and addresses, and 4 buttons. To avoid a long loading process, I want to use the `Community Toolkit Expander`, and place the name in the `Expander.Header` and the remaining items in the body.

The problem is that it is throwing a `NullReferenceException` after the `ListView` or the `CollectionView` loads (I tried with both, and they present the same problem). It is not a problem with my data, because when I just show all the info in a `VerticalStackLayout` there is no exception thrown.

It used to work on a previous version of my app that I developed using `Xamarin.Forms`, so I'm wondering if this might be some kind of bug in `.Net Maui Community Toolkit`, but I haven't found anything about someone else having the same issue.

Here's my code:

```xml
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell x:DataType="m:ProjetoResumo">
                <toolkit:Expander>
                    <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                        <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource WhiteColor}"
                                             Margin="7"
                                             Padding="5">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Nome}"
                                   TextColor="{StaticResource DarkBlueColor}"
                                   FontFamily="MontSemiBold"/>
                            <Image Source="expandarrow.png"
                                   HeightRequest="20"
                                   WidthRequest="20"
                                   HorizontalOptions="End">
                            </Image>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Endereco}"
                               FontSize="Caption"/>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*"
                              HeightRequest="32"
                              Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
                            <ImageButton Source="info.png"
                                         Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <ImageButton Source="phone.png"
                                         Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <ImageButton Source="whatsapp.png"
                                         Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <ImageButton Source="location.png"
                                         Grid.Column="3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </toolkit:Expander>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here's the Call Stack presented by the exception:

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#
0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#
0x1D in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:23,26    C#
0xB in CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Expander. at /_/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Views/Expander/Expander.shared.cs:201,42   C#
0x6 in Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching.Dispatcher. at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Dispatching\Dispatcher.Android.cs:22,24    C#
0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6 C#
0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#
0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22,5  C#
```

Comment: where is the relevant code?  Where is the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @Jason the exception is not thrown within my code, it is thrown after the list loads, I don't know how to get a stack trace of that

Comment: @Jason is the Call Stack presented on the exception enough to find some issue?

Comment: yes, that will generally point to the root cause

Comment: from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander): The Expander control is known to show unwanted behavior when used in a ListView or CollectionView. At this time we recommend not using a Expander in one of these controls.

Comment: Oh damn... do you know any workaround for the Expander? I couldn't find any

Comment: (1) If you limit the number of search results displayed at one time, could use `VerticalStackLayout` inside of `ScrollView`. Caveat is that VerticalStackLayout lays out ALL the children at once, rather than dynamically as scroll. (2) Could have a control above or below the scrolling area, which is filled with the details of a selected item. (3) Could pop up a modal showing details. Not as convenient for your usage, as user then has to close the modal before looking at another one.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I'm working on a pop-up to show the details... not my original design, but at least works

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I created a demo and did a test,and it works properly on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

**ProjetoResumo.cs**

```
public class ProjetoResumo 
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set;}
}
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<ProjetoResumo> Items { get; set; } 

    public MyViewModel() {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ProjetoResumo>();
        Items.Add( new ProjetoResumo { Nome = "test1", Endereco = "end1 " });
        Items.Add(new ProjetoResumo { Nome = "test2", Endereco = "end2 " });
        Items.Add(new ProjetoResumo { Nome = "test3", Endereco = "end3 " });

    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp320.Models"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiApp320.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiApp320.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell x:DataType="local:ProjetoResumo">
                        <toolkit:Expander>
                            <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                <VerticalStackLayout 
                                             Margin="7"
                                             Padding="5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Nome}"
                                     FontFamily="MontSemiBold"/>
                                    <Image Source="arrow.png"
                                   HeightRequest="20"
                                   WidthRequest="20"
                                   HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    </Image>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Endereco}"
                               FontSize="Caption"/>
                                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*"
                              HeightRequest="32"
                              Margin="0, 5, 0, 0">
                                    <ImageButton Source="image1.png"
                                         Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <ImageButton Source="image2.png"
                                         Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <ImageButton Source="image3.png"
                                         Grid.Column="2"/>
                                    <ImageButton Source="image4.png"
                                         Grid.Column="3"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </toolkit:Expander>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I created a new project to test the page alone, and it  worked, like you said, but it's kinda unpredictable... I once scrolled through the list too fast and the exception was thrown again... I'll follow Jason's advice and not use the  Expander inside the ListView